# Networking in objective c Client And Server in Iphone App

Tags: objective-c

i would like make a simple application on iphone had a client and server 
the app should let me send update from client to server and send update from server to client 
the Question is... what should i read about to learn the major and important thing to start doing this application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out gamekit. Connecting to the game network will allow your apps to talk to each other sending small data packets back and forth.

http://imagineric.ericd.net/2011/04/20/ios-gamekit-iphone-to-iphone-communication/

or you can use a TCP socket setup and communicate that way.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

If the ios devices are on the same network it can work from one to the other.

If they are on other networks you will need a central server.

Comment: Thank You i think this could be useful